# Add div to slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am creating an easy slider with image and paragraph at each slide(). I have a problem creating a new div. I've tried everything, but things that worked with image-only slider do not work now (slider doesn't slide at all, even new divs aren't being created). Could anyone bring light to what may be causing this error to occur? I have the following code:

```
var slide = function () {

    if (number_of_image <= 1) number_of_image++;
    else number_of_image = 0;

    $('div.slider:first-of-type').after("<div class='slider'><img src='" + images[number_of_image] + "' alt='" + alts[number_of_image] + "' /></div>");

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    $('div.slider:last-of-type').css({
        'display': 'inline-block',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': $('div.slider:first-of-type').position().top + 'px',
            'left': windowWidth + 'px'
    });
    $('div.slider:first-of-type').animate({
        left: '-' + windowWidth + 'px'
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            $('div.slider:first-of-type').remove();
        }
    });
    $('div.slider:last-of-type').animate({
        left: 0
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        queue: false
    });
}


var time = 10000;

var tick = function () {
    time -= 100;
    if (time <= 0) {
        slide();
        time = 10000;
    }
}

setInterval(tick, 100);
```

**EDIT:** I have an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"
on the following line:

```
'top': $('div.slider:first-of-type').position().top + 'px',
```

Comment: What is the error which you are getting from this code?

Comment: I don't have any error on Brackets. But, I think, there's smth wrong with css setting, because when I made many alerts, there wasn't an alert that css props are set

Comment: run it, open web console in browser and check for errors, not in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that what is being returned from position in that line of code is `undefined`  which does not have a property `top`.

This should only happen when position is unable to calculate the position of the elements. I tried your code and at first got the error you having and then I made sure to add `<div class="slider"></div>` elements to the page and then it worked. Check out this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/9rDAm/2/** which uses the code you posted and was slightly modified. You should see that having elements on the page that `position()` can calculate fixes the problem. Also make sure the elements are not hidden.

The following bit taken from the jquery documentation for `.position()`:  http://api.jquery.com/position/

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the position coordinates of
>   hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on
>   the body element.